# some thing is not fixed in new angularjs version.How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Here I created some sample for date picker which is working fine if I used angular 1.0.8 this version if I used angularjs 1.3.15 is not working..In coding anything I need to change? may I know what was the problem in coding please help on this. .. thanks

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker'])

app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-datepicker ng-options="datepickerOptions"   ng-model="ngModel">',
    scope: {
      date: '=',
      ngModel: '=',
      min: '=',
      max: '=',
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.datepickerOptions = {
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        weekStart: 0,
        startDate :'2013-07-23',
        endDate:'2015-07-23'
      };
    }
  };
})

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.date = '2013-08-12'
}]);

var appboot = angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/cletourneau/angular-bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/cletourneau/angular-bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<body>
<div>
     <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <my-datepicker ng-model ="date"  min="2013-07-23"   max="2015-07-23"></my-datepicker>
     <input id="datepickerMirror" type="text"  data-ng-model="date">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using old version of bootstrap.js...suggest you check repos of datepicker scripts for current versions and dependency compatibility with angular version. Even angular 1.3 isn't current. What errors are thrown? A demo would also help

Comment: edit my code change the version and see.

Comment: `is not working` - do you get any console errors?

Comment: yes if I change the version